# Use drawable pattern as button background

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I am trying the change a button background from a solid color to a dawable image with transparent background to make sure I can see the pattern

I moved to jetpack so I have created

```
Button(onClick = { /*TODO*/ },
            colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
                backgroundColor = colorResource(id = R.color.gainsboro_00)),
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(60.dp),
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(0.dp)) {
            Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.login),
                color = colorResource(id = R.color.gainsboro_05),
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.body1)
        }
```

This button has a grey background.

I would like to apply the drawable below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<bitmap
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/pattern_stripe_loose_gainsboro_05"
    android:tileMode="repeat"/>
```

as a background instead of the colored one and have the pattern displayed. the above xml is just repeating a pattern to create a background

So I expect this:

[image]

using the pattern:

[image]

When using the traditional way with layout and so on it works but I can't make it work on jetpack

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compose does not have such a feature yet. You can create a feature request on [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=612128).

Before this is implemented, you could create a pure Compose solution that draws a lot of images, but I think there is no point in doing that when there is `ImageView` already optimized by engineers. In such cases you can use [`AndroidView`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/interop/interop-apis#views-in-compose) for interop with old views.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun TileAndroidImage(
    @DrawableRes drawableId: Int,
    contentDescription: String,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val drawable = remember(drawableId) {
        BitmapDrawable(
            context.resources,
            BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                context.resources,
                drawableId
            )
        ).apply {
            tileModeX = Shader.TileMode.REPEAT
            tileModeY = Shader.TileMode.REPEAT
        }
    }
    AndroidView(
        factory = {
            ImageView(it)
        },
        update = { imageView ->
            imageView.background = drawable
        },
        modifier = modifier
            .semantics {
                this.contentDescription = contentDescription
                role = Role.Image
            }
    )
}
```

Next part, is puttin it in background of the button. In compose we use containers to do so. You can create your `TiledButton`. I pass zero padding to container button and add real padding manually so it'll not affect the background:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun TiledButton(
    onClick: () -> Unit,
    @DrawableRes backgroundDrawableId: Int,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    enabled: Boolean = true,
    shape: Shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.small,
    border: BorderStroke? = null,
    contentColor: Color = MaterialTheme.colors.primary,
    contentPadding: PaddingValues = ButtonDefaults.ContentPadding,
    content: @Composable RowScope.() -> Unit
) {
    Button(
        onClick = onClick,
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(0.dp),
        enabled = enabled,
        shape = shape,
        border = border,
        elevation = null,
        colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
            backgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
            contentColor = contentColor,
            disabledBackgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
            disabledContentColor = contentColor.copy(alpha = ContentAlpha.disabled),
        ),
        modifier = modifier
    ) {
        Box(
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
        ) {
            TileAndroidImage(
                drawableId = backgroundDrawableId,
                contentDescription = "...",
                modifier = Modifier.matchParentSize()
            )
            Row(
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                modifier = Modifier.padding(contentPadding),
                content = content,
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
TiledButton(
    onClick = { /*TODO*/ },
    backgroundDrawableId = R.drawable.tile,
    border = BorderStroke(1.dp, Color.Blue),
) {
    Text("Apple")
}
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Why not just create a box with that background and place a text while making the entire box clickable? The box will act as the entire button. I mean that's what a button essentially is, isn't it? A box containing some text? Oh, if you cannot figure out a way to get the drawable set as a background on your Box, just use something like an `Image` combined with the `fillMaxSize()` Modifier.

Something like

```
Box(Modifier.fillMaxWidth().height(...), 
 horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.CenterHorizontally){
 Image(painter = painterResource(R.drawable.b_pattern), 
contentDescription = "Lorem Ipsum")
 Text(modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterVertically), 
 text = "Lorem Ipsum")
}
```

Just try it out and let me know please.

Comment: Oh and if you think this might not be the best practice, it is.

Comment: Read the question carefully. Author needs to tile the area with a single image, not just to place it in the background

Comment: Oh, yeah. Sorry bout that. I'll see if it can be achieved

Comment: I think I have seen something similar before